# Error installing pgcrypto extension

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto

I want to install the pgcrypto extension on my postgresql installation on Windows. I found that I just have to call `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` but I've got an error :

```
Syntax error on « CREATE »
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto) AS...
```

(I'm on **PostgreSQL 9.2.4** and I executed the sql line from phpPgAdmin with *postgres* user)

Comment: Now you have a description of how to do that - why do you do it differently?  CREATE ... cannot be part of a subquery.

Comment: I really typed `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` on the text field but it seems to automatically transform my query in `SELECT ... FROM (CREATE ..`.
Well, you tell me it can't be part of a subquery so I'll try to execue my query differently. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As dezso said in the comment, the problem was that CREATE can't be part of a subquery. And phpPgAdmin *transform* the query before executing it so it had put the CREATE as a subquery.

So the solution was to execute the CREATE query in PgAdmin for example.

Comment: Interesting.  So this doesn't work in phpPgAdmin?  That's one for the record.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Utility statements cannot be mixed with DML in PostgreSQL.  They are fundamentally different and get executed entirely differently (for example no planning goes into them).

You should just run

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcryto;
```